# Write a program that asks the user for a number N and a choice C

Tags: java

Write a program that asks the user for a number N and a choice C. And then give him the possibility to choose between computing the sum and computing the product of 1 ,..., N.

If user enters C is equal to

1 : Print sum of 1 to N numbers

2 : Print product of 1 to N numbers

Any other number : print -1

Input format :

Line 1 : Integer N

Line 2 : Choice C (1 or 2)

for this i did not get the exact result of it.what is wrong in this code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sum_OrProduct {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        int choice = sc.nextInt();
        int sum = 0, prod = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            if (choice == 1) {
                sum = sum + i;
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                prod = prod * i;
            } else {
                System.out.println(-1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        System.out.println(prod);
    }

}
```

**Result**

```
Your Output
55
1
```

**Expected Output**

```
55
```

Comment: Well based on what you said your result vs expected is, remove `System.out.println(prod);`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly,
use your if statement above the logic (sum or product),
after you decide to do which operation then code the logic in statement blocks
so you can set your result to a variable in different conditions like below;

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int num=sc.nextInt();
    int choice=sc.nextInt();
    int result;

    switch(choice) 
    {
      case 1: //sum
        result = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<=num;i++) {
          result += i;
        }
      break;

      case 2: //product
        result = 1;
        for(int i=1; i<=num; i++) {
          result *= i;
        }
      break;

      default: //invalid op
        result = -1;
      break;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of if and else statement to check whether it is a sum or product inside a for loop was not giving the right results, so first if the user wants to do sum or product is checked and based on that calculations are done.

```
    int result =0;
    int mult=1;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);  
    System.out.println("Enter a number?");
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Do you want to compute the sum or product?");
    //1 for sum, 2 for product 
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    
            if(b==1){
                for ( int i=1; i<=a; i++) { 
                result += i;
                }
                System.out.println(result);
            }
            else if(b==2){
                for (int i=1; i<=a; i++) {  
                    mult = mult*i;
                    }
                System.out.println(mult);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect");
            }
```

Comment: Can you explain your code, what it does and what you change ?

Comment: @Elikill58 Sure, so instead of if and else statement to check whether it is a sum or product inside a for loop was not giving the right results, so first if the user wants to do sum or product is checked and based on that calculations are done.

Comment: Can you include it in your answer thanks to [edit] ? :) that will be faster for other people to see it !

Answer (score -1):

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Write your code here
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    int c=sc.nextInt();
    if(c==1)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            sum=sum+i;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
    else if(c==2)
    {
        int result=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            result=result*i;
        }
        System.out.println(result);            
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("-1");
    }

}
```

}